# JavaScript can not find Vaadin component id..?

Tags: javascript, function, onclick, vaadin7

My code as follow and Javascript doesn't find any component...Maybe javascript load firstly may be other.. Can you tell me what's wrong?

Thanks..

```
Tab myTab = new Tab(); 

myTab.setId("componentId"); 

JavaScript.getCurrent().execute("$(document).ready(function(){ "+

"$('#componentId').click(function(){ "+

                     "alert('clicked..');"+

                        "});"+

                        "});");
```

Comment: What is the context of the above code?  When is it being executed, i.e. button click handler, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution, It should be add query library URL to application html document header..

http://geekofficedog.blogspot.com.tr/2013/10/add-jquery-to-vaadin-7-application.html

Thanks..